# ui-calendar is not working, not rendering events

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I have declared in my controller an array of events, per documentation

```
    eventSources: [
        {
            events: [
                { title: 'event1', start: '2017-09-27' },
                { title: 'event2', start: '2017-09-27', end: '2017-09-27' },
                { title: 'event3', start: '2017-09-27T12:30:00', }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I added calendar component with ng-model defined (vm is an alias for controller).

**Instead of a calendar, populated with these events, I see a blank calendar and tons of error messages that dont tell me anything. What is wrong?**

[image]

[image]

Someone asked to put full code, not sure how this is going to help, but here it is, calendar.component.ts:

```
namespace AppDomain {

    class CalendarComponent {
        public bindings: any;
        public controller: any;
        public controllerAs: string;
        public templateUrl: string;

        constructor() {
            this.controller = CalendarController;
            this.controllerAs = 'vm';
            this.templateUrl = '/app/calendar/calendar.component.html';
        }
    }

    class CalendarController {
        eventSources: [
            {
                events: [
                    { title: 'event1', start: '2017-09-27' },
                    { title: 'event2', start: '2017-09-27', end: '2017-09-27' },
                    { title: 'event3', start: '2017-09-27T12:30:00', }
                ]
            }
        ]

        constructor() { }

        $onInit() { }
    }

    angular.module('app').component('calendarComponent', new CalendarComponent());
}
```

And calendar.component.html:

```
<div ui-calendar ng-model="vm.eventSources"></div>
```

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

Even if I add ui-calendar like this, without any ng-model for events,

```
<div ui-calendar></div>
```

just a blank calendar, I still get all these errors

**UPDATE2**

I tried this of course as well:

```
    events2: [
        { title: 'event1', start: '2017-09-27' },
        { title: 'event2', start: '2017-09-27', end: '2017-09-27' },
        { title: 'event3', start: '2017-09-27T12:30:00', }
    ]
```

and then

Same problem

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: You think its going to help you?

Comment: Here, added the code!

Comment: I'm a bit confused... this is TypeScript with Angular 1.x, right? I'm wondering if the error is because you haven't used `$scope` on your `events`?

Comment: vm is used instead of $scope as an alias

Comment: Okay. Well I'm assuming that the error is being thrown in relation to the `events`, is that what you're thinking?

Comment: yes, I am writing my AngularJS components code in TypeScript

Comment: I have no idea why I get all these errors, they come (as you ca see) from http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js, the code of that library. If I just leave  <div ui-calendar></div>, I get same bunch of errors

Comment: It looks like the directive is using the `.length` property of `vm.eventSources` somewhere. In the docs, I see that their `events` array is an array of objects - https://www.screencast.com/t/1rkokyXygA. Have you tried not nesting your `events` inside an object?

Comment: Yes, of course, I tried to pass just an array of events as well, it looks like these are not related, since the errors come even without specifying ng-model

Comment: Try to reproduce this error in Fiddle to be sure its not your env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use empty `ui-calendar` a.e. `<div ui-calendar></div>`

It should be configured by `ng-model`

```
<div ng-model="events" ui-calendar="options"></div>
```

where `events` is a list of events and options (optional) - calendar configuration

---

So your problem is in events structure

`eventSources` should be array of arrays

For example:

```
[
  [
    {
      "title": "Long Event",
      "start": "2017-09-27",
      "end": "2017-09-27"
    }
  ]
]
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f0b85os/)