# How to re-draw (re-render) the ui-calendar when events arrive (via promise)?

Tags: angularjs, calendar

To continue my previous post: [ui-calendar is not working, not rendering events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430556/ui-calendar-is-not-working-not-rendering-events)

I am using angularjs ui-calendar that accepts an array of events as ng-model to display them in the calendar.

The problem is that the events must be ready and defined before the browser renders the calendar.

I have events defined like this in the controller:

```
    events2 = [{
        title: 'Event1',
        start: '2017-09-27',
        end: '2017-09-27'
    }];
    events3 = [{
        title: 'Event2',
        start: '2017-09-28',
        end: '2017-09-28'
    }];
```

Then in $onInit (or in the controller's constructor) I set:

```
this.eventSources = [this.events2, this.events3];
```

And in HTML I define component as:

```
<div ng-model="vm.eventSources" ui-calendar></div>
```

Everything works fine.

However, as you see, the events are hardcoded and are available before the calendar is rendered.

In my real situation I get event by calling Google Calendar API and the events are returned with a delay (via a promise), so, when I get the events from a Google Service, I need to trigger a REDRAW of the calendar.

How can I do that? ui-calendar is not a simple HTML control that will display changes when ng-model is changed, but a third party component, so, in this situation I need to trigger a re-render of the calendar after the events arrive.

Any idea how to do that?

This is the method that calls Google Service to get the events:

```
    getCalendarEvents() {
        console.log('getCalendarEvents');
        this.service.getCalendarEvents().then(events => {
            //this.events = <CalendarEvent[]>events;
            this.eventSources = [this.events2, this.events3];
        });
    }
```

Even if I use hardcoded events after **then** the calendar does not display them, it needs to be redrawn with a new value in this.eventSources

**Please advice!** using $scope.$apply() has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Resolve](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx) in angularJS.
Resolve will call your service bring the data before loading/executing controller, so you can get your data before your view and controller are loaded/executed and then you can inject it as a dependency in your controller to get the data.

Here is my working code snippet.

```js
.state('abc', {
  controller : 'controller',
  controllerAs : 'controllerAs',
  resolve : {
    getProjectData : ['MyService', '$state',
      function(MyService, $state) {
          return MyService.getProjectDetails();
      }]
  }
  
  app.controller('controller', ['getProjectData', function(getProjectData) {
    console.log(getProjectData);  // Here you will get all your data
    vm.data = getProjectData;
    
  //setting schedule list in fullcalendar
 vm.eventSources.push({events : vm.data});
  }]);
```

```html
<div ui-calendar="controller.uiConfig.calendar" id="calendar" ng-model="controller.eventSources"></div>
```